# I am faceing the issue regarding URL

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

i have to get just 2 parameter in URL in this order
http://localhost/StudentGuideBook/AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?type=Govermnet&Category=University

i will get this first time when i click on the two value but after this i will getting this type of link 
http://localhost/StudentGuideBook/AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?type=Govermnet&Category=University&Category=College&type=Govermnet

i want to override the value is the link not to concate this 
anny solutions ???

in the code i have check the Complete URL of server as 
$CompleteLink = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

```html
<div class="just-padding">
                <div class="list-group list-group-root well">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Search By Type</a>
                    <div class="list-group">
                       <?php
                        if (strpos($CompleteLink, $mark) !== false){
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&type=Private' class='list-group-item'>Private Institutes</a>";
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&type=Govermnet' class='list-group-item'>Goverment Institutes</a>";
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&type=all' class='list-group-item'>All Institutes</a>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?type=Private' class='list-group-item'>Private Institutes</a>";
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?type=Govermnet' class='list-group-item'>Goverment Institutes</a>";
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?type=all' class='list-group-item'>All Institutes</a>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group list-group-root well">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Search By Category</a>
                    <div class="list-group">
                         <?php
                        if (strpos($CompleteLink, $mark) !== false){
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&Category=University' class='list-group-item'>University</a>";
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&Category=College' class='list-group-item'>College</a>";
                            echo "<a href='$CompleteLink&Category=Technical Academy' class='list-group-item'>Technical Academy</a>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?Category=University' class='list-group-item'>University</a>";
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?Category=College' class='list-group-item'>College</a>";
                            echo "<a href='" . BASE_URL . "AdminPanel/viewInstitute.php?Category=Technical Academy' class='list-group-item'>Technical Academy</a>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: This is the link i am getting]

Comment: will this question if answered also remain in the "unsolved" part of Stack? You should mark the questions that were solved as "solved", otherwise people may post more answers thinking they're not solved.

Comment: this is the unsolved question and i will marked my othr question as solved

Answer (score 0):

I think somehow `$CompleteLink` is mutated before it is echoed. 
If you don't want to hustle through your code to find where it is mutated, you can try to do `$CompleteString = substr($CompleteLink, 0, (strpos($CompleteLink, '?')));` right before you echo it